# How can I convert a datetime string into an integer datatype?

Tags: java, string, date, integer

```
String timerStop1 = String.format("%02d", hours) + ":"+String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":"
                  + String.format("%02d", seconds);
```

I'm taking the above concatenated string value and I want to convert it into an **integer** to use in my android application.  How do I do this?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(Your String);

Comment: By convert to an integer do you mean the number of seconds in total?

Comment: Can you tell us what the integer will be used for?

Comment: `timerStop1` would be something like "10:30:12". If you convert this to integer using `Integer.parseInt`, you would get a NumberFormatException. So you need to tell how you are defining the conversion of this string to integer.

Comment: @ColinGillespie int is used to calculate speed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first step will be to convert the time in **HH:MM:SS** format (which is how your string is formatted) to that of seconds as per the following:

```
String timerStop1 = String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds);
String[] timef=timerStop1.split(":");  

int hour=Integer.parseInt(timef[0]);  
int minute=Integer.parseInt(timef[1]);  
int second=Integer.parseInt(timef[2]);  

int temp;  
temp = second + (60 * minute) + (3600 * hour);  

System.out.println("seconds " + temp);
```

**However, this only gets the time as seconds (integers), but not as a timestamp!**

UPDATE:

And, as Colin pointed out, given that you already have access to the variables: hours, minutes, seconds - why not do it like what he suggested - which is completely correct?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15307211/866930

That's because the OP wants to know how to convert an HH:MM:SS string to an integer - if so, then this is the most general way in which to do so, IMO.

Comment: It is not possible, answer will be not proper

Comment: If you have access to the variables why not use my solution. But I guess this is the only way if you can only use the string.

Comment: @ColinGillespie, I agree - it could also be an exercise in conversion from time-strings. However, since the OP requested: `concatenated string value and I want to convert it into an integer`, this is as general as you can get (given the parameters stated).

Comment: can u tell me what i change in ansewer to get minute?

Comment: If you mean to find the time in minutes, then change the line containing this: `temp = second + (60 * minute) + (3600 * hour);` to this: `temp = minute + (60 * hour); `. Why no seconds? Because in HH:MM:SS format, seconds will always be less than 60. And, if we were to convert seconds from the HH:MM:SS string to minutes, it will **always** be 0 integer minutes - which is why I did not include it.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks man! I actually needed this for C# so here's the solution converted in case anyone else needs it-

                `string[] timef = Info.LongestHold.Split(new Char[] { ':' });

                int hour;
                int minute;
                int second;

                int.TryParse(timef[0], out hour);
                int.TryParse(timef[1], out minute);
                int.TryParse(timef[2], out second);

                int temp;
                temp = second + (60 * minute) + (3600 * hour);

                Console.WriteLine("seconds " + temp);`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to parse `timerStop1` to integer because `timerStop1` contains characters other than numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use the variables hours, minutes, seconds. Assuming that by converting to an integer you want the total number of seconds.

```
int time = seconds + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 3600);
```

Answer (score -1):

the `tostring()` method hier not necessary

```
Integer.parseInt(timerStop1);
```