# Progress Bar with UTC time

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I have a progress bar, I have to set progress in `int` value, but I have `long` UTC time

example:

```
start = 1474369800000
end = 1474371600000
now = 1474370572206
```

I'm going crazy in seeking the right proportion for setting the advancement of the progress bar (100 intervals) according to the current time and time from now.

Could someone explain to me how to divide the interval correctly ?

Comment: Simply convert long to int

Comment: It isn't so simple , I had already tried it, otherwise I would not have asked the question , please do not voted down if you have not understood the meaning of the question

Comment: i didn't get the scenario. Please explain

Comment: Then get hour , min and sec from your long UTC time

Comment: I need to split the interval of the progress bar ( 100 ) in order to have the correct feed it with respect to the above times

Comment: check out this link might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909075/convert-time-field-hm-into-integer-field-minutes-in-java one more link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307171/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-string-into-an-integer-datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand problem i think it is:

```
(now - start) / ((end-start)/100)
```

so, for the values in your post you get 43/100